# Powermockito mocking static method returning a Mockito.mock

Tags: mocking, powermockito

I've got this piece of code which I'd like to mock using powermockito:

```
long size = FileUtility.getFileFromPath(uri.getPath()).length())
```

Implementation of this static method is simple:

```
public static File getFileFromPath(String filePath) {
    return new File(filePath);
}
```

Now when I write this piece of code in my test, the tests fails.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileUtility.class);
File fileMock = mock(File.class);
PowerMockito.when(FileUtility.getFileFromPath(anyString())).thenReturn(fileMock);
Mockito.doReturn(12).when(fileMock.length());
```

With this exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at nl.mijnverzekering.entities.declareren.NotaPdfMetadataTest.mockFileSize(NotaPdfMetadataTest.java:273)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

I've seen the error before (where I should extract *mock(File.class)* to a seperate variable, like I did now).
What is going wrong here? Is it because I am using a mock-object as return value? How to solve that?

**Workaround solution:**
of course my tests would succeed if I'd add this method to FileUtility:

```
public static long getFileSizeFromFilePath(String filePath) {
    return getFileFromPath(filePath).length();
}
```

and then simply

```
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileUtility.class);
    PowerMockito.when(FileUtility.getFileSizeFromFilePath(anyString())).thenReturn(size);
```

But I'd like to prevent adding a list of those unnecessary methods to my FileUtility (and understand the reason for the Exception)

Answer (score 0):

> What is going wrong here? Is it because I am using a mock-object as
>   return value? How to solve that?

This line is wrong:

```
Mockito.doReturn(12).when(fileMock.length());
```

The signature is `T when(T mock)`, so the mock should be passed, but not the method invocation:

```
Mockito.doReturn(12L).when(fileMock).length();
```

This also would work:

```
Mockito.when(fileMock.length()).thenReturn(12L);
```